# When moving messages from a room, don't move messages from people whose posts you have hidden

Tags: feature-request, chat

I was just trying to do some cleanup in one of the rooms I frequent - we've got a bot that posts comments into the room at times, and so I was trying to remove the messages that didn't need to be there anymore (especially since some of them had tripped the "offensive" filter and so there was no need to leave them around).

So, to easily find *just* the bot's messages, I hid everyone else's messages temporarily, so only my messages and the bot's were visible to me. I then selected the messages using the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> buttons that you can use to select messages when moving.

Unfortunately, hiding the posts didn't mean that they weren't selected when I used <kbd>shift</kbd>. This resulted in... a bit of [an accident](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42936940#42936940) where I accidentally moved 300 messages to another room (which I then fixed).

But this wouldn't have happened if it **didn't move messages that weren't visible to the one moving**. If the one moving the messages can't see the messages, then don't move the ones they can't see, to prevent mishaps like this in the future. (I assume this works the same way for people that you're ignoring, but I haven't tested.)

So can ROs and mods please not be able to move messages that they can't see?

Comment: If you can use a user script you might like JasonC's [Chat Move Helper Bot Cleanup](https://stackapps.com/questions/7439/chat-move-helper-bot-cleanup-tool) script. I use it in the Tavern to cleanup smokey reports.

Comment: @rene - How does that work with moderator tools? Mods have RO powers in all rooms; how does that work? Will it show up in rooms where I'm not an explicit RO?

Comment: yup - I have it installed (ironically for the tavern) and I see the clean menu on the other chat. And that's exactly what its meant to do sooooo. It will *clean*.

Comment: With great user scripts come great responsibilities ...

Comment: Worst case you add a check [here](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/ChatMoveHelper.user.js#L52) to opt out of all other rooms and only continue in the few rooms you want to have it enabled.